# How to create a payroll report out of an attendance records using PHP

Tags: php

I have database table named: **timesheets** which has the following columns and data:

```
employee_id  employee_name  year  month  day  timein  timeout  department
1            dave           2016  09     15   8       4        finance
1            dave           2016  09     16   8       4        finance
1            dave           2016  09     17   8       4        finance
2            frank          2016  09     15   8       4        purchase
2            frank          2016  09     16   8       4        purchase
```

which records the daily attendance of employees as you can see above. What I want is to create a payroll report from these attendance records using PHP that shows the total number of working hours for each employee with every department in a separate html table like so:

**finance department payroll html table**

```
employe_id | employee_name  | total_working_hours
-----------+----------------+---------------------
1          | dave           | 24 (8 hrs * 3 days)
```

**purchase department payroll html table**

```
employe_id | employee_name  | total_working_hours
-----------+----------------+---------------------
1          | frank          | 16
```

Please note that I don't know the ID's of all employees, so the code should just list everyone grouped by department using PHP / MYSQL

Comment: Why didn't you use any DB?

Comment: I mean, do you use a database system to store and fetch your data?

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Couldn't think of anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of views will do the job: One for working hours, one for employees, then you can join them and and program your filters, like this:

```
-- Query the working hours
CREATE VIEW
 vw_working_hours
AS
SELECT
    employee_id,
    year,
    month, 
    SUM((timeout+12) - timein ) AS total_working_hours 
FROM
    timesheets
GROUP BY
    employee_id,
    year,
    month;

-- Query the employees
CREATE VIEW
    vw_employees
AS

SELECT 
    DISTINCT
    employee_id,
    employee_name,
    department
FROM
    timesheets;

-- This query is the actual report
-- just had to filter by department
-- in your script
SELECT
    wh.employee_id,
    emp.employee_name,
    wh.total_working_hours
FROM
    vw_working_hours AS wh
JOIN
    vw_employees AS emp
ON
    wh.employee_id = emp.employee_id
WHERE
    wh.year = 2016
    AND
        wh.month = '09'
    AND
        emp.department = 'finance';
```

Or, in a single query (no views):

```
SELECT
    wh.employee_id,
    emp.employee_name,
    wh.total_working_hours
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        employee_id,
        year,
        month, 
        SUM((timeout+12) - timein ) AS total_working_hours 
    FROM
        timesheets
    GROUP BY
        employee_id,
        year,
        month

    ) AS wh
JOIN
    (
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT
        employee_id,
        employee_name,
        department
    FROM
        timesheets

    ) AS emp
ON
    wh.employee_id = emp.employee_id
WHERE
    wh.year = 2016
    AND
        wh.month = '09'
    AND
        emp.department = 'finance';
```

In php you should use a loop and an accumulated variable. First you should pre-filter with a query like this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  timesheets
WHERE
  department = 'finance'
  AND
    year = 2016
  AND
    month = '09'
  ORDER BY
    employee_id;
```

Then if the result is in a multidimensional array named $rows, something in php like this:

```
$employee_id = $rows[0]['employee_id'];
    $employee_name = $rows[0]['employee_name'];
    $accumulated = 0;

    foreach($rows as $row) {
      $total_working_hours = ($row['timeout'] + 12) - $row['timein'];
      if ( $row['employee_id'] == $employee_id ) {
        //  Same employee, acumulate
        $accumulated += $total_working_hours;
      } else {
        //  Another employee, pass the acumulation to result
        $rowTmp['employee_id'] = $employee_id;
        $rowTmp['employee_name'] = $employee_name;
        $rowTmp['total_working_hours'] = $accumulated;
        $result[] = $rowTmp;
        //  Updated the accumulation variables
        //  new employee
        $employee_id = $row['employee_id'];
        $employee_name = $row['employee_name'];
        //  reset accumulated
        $accumulated = $total_working_hours;
      }
    }

    // at the end, updates the las result:
    $rowTmp['employee_id'] = $employee_id;
    $rowTmp['employee_name'] = $employee_name;
    $rowTmp['total_working_hours'] = $accumulated;
    $result[] = $rowTmp;

    // Should pass result to HTML table
    print_r( $result );
```

Comment: I'll try this, then I'll report back. Thank you so much.

Comment: isn't there a way to do that in php? it looks so complicated to me since I only have little knowledge about SQL

Comment: The views are created only once, you don't need them in your query once they are created. If already created, remove them from your script, then just run it again. Keep just the last part, from "This query is the actual..." to bottom.

Comment: I've edited the answer in order to work without views, you can check it out.

Comment: I've edited again for example in php, choose your flavor.

Comment: Thank you for this great effort you put into helping me. I really appreciate it. Thanks man.